# Java paint speed relative to color model

Tags: java, paint, bufferedimage

I have a BufferedImage with an IndexColorModel.  I need to paint that image onto the screen, but I've noticed that this is slow when using an IndexColorModel.  However, if I run the BufferedImage through an identity affine transform it creates an image with a DirectColorModel and the painting is significantly faster.  Here's the code I'm using

```
AffineTransformOp identityOp = new AffineTransformOp(new AffineTransform(), AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
displayImage = identityOp.filter(displayImage, null);
```

I have three questions

1.  Why is painting the slower on an IndexColorModel? 
2.  Is there any way to speed up the painting of an IndexColorModel? 
3.  If the answer to 2. is no, is this the most efficient way to convert from an IndexColorModel to a DirectColorModel?  I've noticed that this conversion is dependent on the size of the image, and I'd like to remove that dependency.

Thanks for the help

Comment: How are you creating the BufferedImage?

Comment: I'm creating it through dcm4che using version 1.4.  It's a very complicated project.  What specific information would you like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment...

Are you sure that the *BufferedImage* you're creating are the best depending on the OS you're on? You should *always* create a "compatible" BufferedImage.  The fastest on, say, Windows, may be `TYPE_INT_ARGB` but this is not true on OS X and vice-versa.

Something like this (ouch, the Law of Demeter hurts ;)   :

```
GraphicsEnvironment
        .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
        .getDefaultScreenDevice()
        .getDefaultConfiguration()
        .createCompatibleImage(width, height,Transparency.TRANSLUCENT)
```

Comment: I can't control the initial ColorModel.  I have to call a function which returns to me an IndexColorModel.  I then call displayImage = new BufferedImage(cm, displayImage.getRaster(), false, null) where cm is an IndexColorModel.  Is there a better way to integrate this IndexColorModel?